# Make a multidimensional array in PHP from mysql result

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have query result like this

**Query result Table**:

[image]

I need to display this data to html table view like

**HTMLTable**:

[image]

So **how should i convert this result array variable in to such PHP array variable** so i can loop that array variable and display the result according to attached html Table view

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: For starters: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php , http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

One way is you can use mysql_fetch_assoc() function in a loop like this :

```
// The array which will store all questions
$questions = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   // Put in the array questions an array per question using mysql fieldsnames

   // if a question with main_question_id=2 exists 
   if (!isset($questions[$row['main_question_id'])) {

      //build your question and put it in your array
      $questions[$row['main_question_id']] = array(
         'question_num' => $row['main_question_number'],
         'description' => $row['descritption'],
         'obtained_mark' => $row['obtained_mark'],
         // etc ...
      );
   }
}

// Displays description for question 2 for example :
echo $questions[2]['description'];
```

Then you can build your html (were also doable during first loop)

```
// Builds head of html table
$html = '<table><tr><th>Question Number</th><th>Desc.</th><th>Mark</th></tr>';

// Builds html content table with another loop
foreach ($questions as $question){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$question["main_number_question"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$question["description"].'</td>';
    $html .= '<td>'.$question["obtained_mark"].'</td>';
    $html .= '</tr>';
}

// build the bottom of table
$html .= '</table>;


// Displays all table
echo $html;
```

Dont forget to check doc and comments behind her here : 
http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc

You can also use 
http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for the reply bro but i already have fetched result in to a PHP array variable but i need to store these rows in to multi dimensional array like **main_question > sub_question > child_question **